# What data type should I use to store google-map addresses

Tags: mysql, google-maps

I've tried googling this question but it seems like there's no answer yet. I'd like to be able to store any google map address that exists. I'm thinking of using `VARCHAR(255)` but am not sure if that's overkill or maybe even under the longest address they have.

Since I'd like this to also include non-english, I'm not sure if certain characters will end up taking more space as well. By default my tables should be `utf8_general_ci` with engine `InnoDB` (I can also change it if it helps).

There's a long location name like:

```
Taumatawhakatangihangakoauauotamateaturipukakapiki-maungahoronukupokaiwhenuakitanatahu
```

So I'm thinking `VARCHAR(255)` but would like a more definite answer.

Answer (score 1):

Since the 5.0.3 version MySQL supports VARCHARs up to 65.535 bytes long, adding a single byte of length info when the length surpasses 255 bytes. 
I would have opted for a longer VARCHAR as the only overhead is the one added byte, and stored the data UTF-encoded.

Comment: do you know what the longest address is?

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't. That's why I would leave plenty of headroom for any potentially very long address.